# Why aren't spaces contravariant functors?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

The *functor of points* approach to algebraic geometry often starts with the definition of a *k-space* as an object in the functor category $\mathsf{Sp}_k=\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Comm}_k,\mathsf{Set})$. That is, a **covariant** functor from the category of commutative $k$-algebras to the category of sets.

We can define $\mathsf{Aff}_k=\mathsf{Comm}_k^{\mathrm{op}}$ and then rewrite $\mathsf{Sp}_k=\mathrm{PShv}(\mathsf{Aff}_k)=\mathrm{Fun}(\mathsf{Comm}_k,\mathsf{Set})$.

But a motivating example for the functor of points approach is by thinking of $\mathrm{Hom}(-,B)$, a **contravariant** functor, as a space, where we map a commutative $k$-algebra $A$ to some set of points in $B^n$ (when $A$ is finitely generated) determined by $A$.

What am I doing wrong here?
I'm sure I must have got lost amidst all the opposites somewhere, but can't track it down.

Comment: Isn't the motivating example for the functor of points usually considered to be $\text{Hom}(B,-)$?

Comment: @alexsaad I wondered that, but it doesn't seem as intuitive, or at least not to me. Either way, the wikipedia page on the hom functor says that it is the contravariant functor that gives the functor of points approach (and I don't trust myself enough to argue with even wikipedia)

Comment: Ah, OK - I think in Wikipedia's case (if I've found the bit you were referring to) the contravariant Hom functor is considered as the functor of points on the category of affine $k$-schemes rather than on its dual. This makes sense with regarding a "$Y$-point" on a scheme $X$ as a morphism $Y\rightarrow X$.

Comment: The way I like to think of the corresponding covariant functor $\text{Hom}(B,-)$ on the category of $k$-algebras is that if $B$ is some polynomial ring modded out by a polynomial $f$ (say), then this functor sends every algebra $A$ to the set of points on a "variety" over $A$ cut out by the solutions to $f$. So the identification of a scheme with its functor of points is saying that a scheme basically gives you a "variety" of a certain shape over every ring/algebra. I wrote a blog post about this recently which may (or may not!) help: http://bit.ly/1mkAe8I :)

Comment: I'll have a read through when I have time later, but at a quick glance it looks very helpful, thanks! If you fancy posting a quick explanation as an answer then I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical example used to motivate the functor of points approach is actually the *covariant* functor $\text{Hom}(B,-):\text{Comm}_k \rightarrow \text{Set}$. Here's a basic example as to why: suppose $B = k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/I$ where $I$ is an ideal generated by polynomials $g_1, \dots, g_m$, and let $X = \text{Spec}(B)$. Then $k$-algebra morphisms $B\rightarrow R$ correspond to simultaneous solutions of the polynomials $g_1, \dots, g_m$ in $R$, so the set $\text{Hom}(B,R)$ of all such morphisms corresponds to the set of points $X(R) = \left\{P\in R^n: g_i (P) = 0, \forall i\right\}$. From a geometrical point of view, the functor $\text{Hom}(B,-)$ produces the set of points of a "variety" in $R^n$, cut out by the polynomials generating $I$, in a way compatible with morphisms.

Thinking categorically, $\text{Hom}(B,-)$ is "the same" as the presheaf $\text{Hom}(-,\text{Spec}(B))$ on the category of affine schemes, which via the Yoneda lemma is the image of $\text{Spec}(B)$ in the larger category of presheaves on the category of affine schemes. This is the identification between a space $\text{Spec}(B)$  and the presheaf it represents.

Answer (score 3):

The motivation for the functor of points is actually $\operatorname{Hom}(-, \operatorname{Spec}(B))$, which, when composed with $\operatorname{Spec}$, gives the functor $\operatorname{Hom}(B,-) : \mathsf{Comm} \to \mathsf{Set}$. It's a contravariant functor when defined on schemes, and a covariant functor when defined on commutative algebras (through $\operatorname{Spec}$). Then you replace $\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ by a more general scheme $X$ to get $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(-,X)$.

To recall it easily, recall the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1 = \operatorname{Spec} k[x]$: one has
$$\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Comm}_k}(k[x], A) \cong A, \quad f \mapsto f(x)$$
(which is what one would expect from a 1-dimensional line), and this is also $\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathsf{Sch}}(\operatorname{Spec} A, \mathbb{A}^1)$.

Comment: This is also a great answer, thank you